# How to filter on a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

The table has 3 fields and sample data.

```
customerid  ordertype   countoforders
1           APP         10
1           WEB         20
2           APP         10
3           WEB         10
4           APP         30
5           APP         40
5           WEB         10
```

I want to retrieve only APP order customers and it counts. How can I write the query for the same?

For example from above table APP only customers are 2 and 4.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple where clause on the ordertype column will get you the desired results

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: simple where clause lists all APP orders but i want only customers ordering APP only it should not include WEB orders

Comment: I don't think the requirements are at all clear here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what DBMS you're using, so I'll have to avoid making product specific recommendations.

If this is really urgent the UGLIEST way to achieve what you require would be to create a lookup table with all the 'WEB' orders you have in your table (customerid, ordertype) and perform a `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` on that table (ex. `SELECT customerid, ordertype, countoforders FROM TABLE_1 WHERE TABLE_1.customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid FROM #lookup)`)

Performance-wise it may not be optimal but this would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select customerid, countoforders from MY_TABLE
where ordertype = 'APP'
except
select customerid, countoforders from MY_TABLE
where ordertype <> 'APP'
```

Comment: I'd do `where ordertype <> 'APP'` in second select, just in case.